# SQLAlchemy: Use like() on a relationship()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a setup that looks like this:

```
class Name(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('name.id'))

    _name = db.relationship('Name')

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name.name
```

Calling Person.name returns a string containing their actual name, for example.

I'm building a RESTful API based on this. I need to allow searches with wildcards based on the Person's name. The functionality I'm looking for is:

`Person.query.filter(Person.name.like('Z%'))` would select Zack, Zed, Zoo, etc. However, you cannot use `.like()` on `name` because it is a Property, not a Column.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relationship is called `_name`, so you need to use it as such in the query. You'll want to do something like this:

```
people = DBSession.query(Person)\
    .join(Person._name)\
    .filter(Name.name.like('Z%'))\
    .all()

# or more explicitly without using the relationship:

people = DBSession.query(Person)\
    .join(Name, Person.name_id == Name.id)\
    .filter(Name.name.like('Z%'))\
    .all()
```

As an aside, it seems a little weird to have a Person class and a Name class... but perhaps it is justified by your use case.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins

Comment: I get `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: integer ~~* unknown LINE 3: WHERE node.id ILIKE '' AND node.ipaddress ILIKE '' AND node.... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` The Person and Name stuff in the question was just an example. I have no idea what could be going wrong here.

Comment: It will help if you post an example of your actual / running code.

Comment: Can you do a simple query using the relationship at all? eg `...query(Person).join(Person._name).filter(Name.id == 1).all()` - just  to make sure the relationship is set up correctly.

Comment: Got it figured out! I had made a mistake in my code unrelated to any of the SQLAlchemy stuff, which was causing some of my filter parameters to break. Thanks for your help with the joins!

Comment: Cool - glad you figured it out :)

Comment: In case anyone else is having the "operator does not exist" issue like mine: do not use LIKE or ILIKE on integers. Those are string comparison functions.